# How to make redirect to thank you page in custom form in Wordpress(not contact form 7 and not ajax)?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, custom-wordpress-pages

In client's theme there is a custom contact form, not a plugin, not a popular ajax form snippet. I see the form like that at first and want to figure out. In its action is a file, that is in the theme too.
The code of the form

```
<form action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/data.php" method="post" id="form2">
              <ul class="clearfix">
                <li><input type="text" name="nameUser" class="required" placeholder="Your name"></li>
                <li><input type="tel" name="phoneUser" class="required phone" placeholder="Your phone"></li>
              </ul>
              <div class="btn-container clearfix">
                <div class="wrap-btn-right">
                    <input type="hidden" name="letter_act" value="<?php echo get_field('letter_action', 'option'); ?>">
                  <button class="btn-gen" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
```

The code of data.php file, where all data from the form is sending

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>New request</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
html {width: 100%;height: 100%;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$to = "$_POST[letter_act]";
$from = "noreply@".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$subject = '=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode('New request:').'?=';
$headers .= 'Return-path: <' . $from . ">\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: request <' . $from . ">\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' . "\r\n\r\n";
$message = "Name: $_POST[nameUser]\n\nPhone: $_POST[phoneUser]";
$mail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if ($mail) {
echo "<body style='background: url(wp-content/themes/pzk-theme/img/bg-general.jpg) no-repeat center; background-size:cover;'><div style='width:260px;height:275px;margin:100px auto;background: #fff;color:#0F5F6A;text-align:center;padding:40px 30px 0;font-size: 130%;font-family: Arial,sans-serif;box-shadow:0 10px 15px rgba(0,0,0, .5);'><p>The form was successfully sent. Thank you! </p><p><a href='/' style='display:block;padding:10px 25px;margin: 10px 0 0;font-size:80%;background:#ff530e;border-radius:90px;border-bottom: 5px solid #d1450a;color:#fff;text-decoration:none;width:100px;margin:40px auto 0;'>To the home page</a></p></div>";
}
else {
  echo "<body style='background: #fff;'><div style='width:260px;height:275px;margin:100px auto;background: #fff;color:#282828;text-align:center;padding:40px 30px 0;border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;border-radius:10px;font-size: 130%;font-family: Arial,sans-serif;box-shadow:0 10px 15px rgba(0,0,0, .5);'><p>Error! Please repeat your attempt later .</p><p><a href='index.html' style='display:block;padding:10px 25px;background:#00b5a0;border-radius:5px;color:#fff;text-decoration:none;text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;width:100px;margin:40px auto 0;'>To the home page</a></p></div>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I searched and found the way - to paste this code on the top of the data.php document

```
<?php header( "refresh:5;url='https://example.com/thank-you/'" );?>
```

It works, redirecting to needed url, but at first after sending it shows the block from

```
if ($mail) {
echo "<body style='background: url(wp-content/themes/pzk-theme/img/bg-general.jpg) no-repeat center; background-size:cover;'><div style='width:260px;height:275px;margin:100px auto;background: #fff;color:#0F5F6A;text-align:center;padding:40px 30px 0;font-size: 130%;font-family: Arial,sans-serif;box-shadow:0 10px 15px rgba(0,0,0, .5);'><p>The form was successfully sent. Thank you! </p><p><a href='/' style='display:block;padding:10px 25px;margin: 10px 0 0;font-size:80%;background:#ff530e;border-radius:90px;border-bottom: 5px solid #d1450a;color:#fff;text-decoration:none;width:100px;margin:40px auto 0;'>To the home page</a></p></div>";
}
```

If I delete it and replace with

```
<?php header( "refresh:5;url='https://example.com/thank-you/'" );?>
```

I see the empty white screen.

I'm new in forms like that. Want to learn more, and to make it right. Maybe it's another correct way, from wordpress itself?

Comment: I have to create thank-you.php in theme instead of simply creation of a wordpress page then? cause now I don't have such a file. There has to be that html from 'if $mail' inside it?

Comment: Sorry forgot this was wordpress

Comment: data.php is a file inside the theme, so I can create thank-you.php too, but I think clients want the page, because example.com/wp-content/themes/pzk-theme/data.php. in fact makes the same function as they want in thank-you page. It's already like thank-you page. Maybe they don't like not ordinary url, I don't know

Comment: I am not a WP expert or any where near one. So ignore what I said

Comment: maybe simply rename the url? if it's possible to trim it, maybe it's easy to change it too and left the file like it is?

Comment: I think it works if ($mail) {
echo "<script> window.location.href = 'example.com/thank-you/'</script>";
} but not sure yet

Answer (score 0):

as you're not validating the data that is being sent on the front-end you can just build a html thank-you page into your data.php (as you're already redirecting the user into it). Just close the php and start building the html stuff...

But the best way for doing what you want is to use ajax, so you can make a request to your php file and depending on the response you can display anything you want.